# How do I read time in min/hr in a dataframe get sales rate?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time

I have a data frame which has hours in min for example 14:59 where 60:00 (max) is 1 (hr).

I tried reading this dataframe using the code below I got an error "Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values"

```
df['time sold'].dt.minute
```

My hope was after reading the date below to get the sale rate per min. 
my data is

```
Name Sales Time
Jame 603   14:59
Sam  903   34:00
Lee  756   34:55
```

Is there a way to get how much each sold be the minute?

```
Name Sales Time    Sale Rate
Jame 603   14:59   xxxx
Sam  903   34:00   yyyy
Lee  756   34:55   zzzz
```

Please excuse the xyz just used them as place holders.

Answer (score 1):

first add the HH to be able to convert it to a pandas timedelta:

```
df['Time'] = '00:'+df['Time'].astype(str)
```

then convert to timedelta

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])
```

then make a new column equal to sales per minute

```
df['Sales Rate'] = df['Sales'] / (df['Time'].dt.total_seconds()/60)
```

output:

```
     Sales     Time Sales Rate
Jame   603 00:14:59    40.2447
Sam    903 00:34:00    26.5588
Lee    756 00:34:55    21.6516
```

Comment: df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'])   i get expected hh:mm:ss format

Comment: did you add the 00 first

Comment: I copied and pasted your data so should work if you add the 00: first so it is a hh:mm:ss format

Comment: I think so. I even tried making df = k, where k show time as for eg (00:37:12)  then i did k['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(k['Time']). But still get the error "expected hh:mm:ss format". Thank you btw in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following if you have datetime dtype in time column:

```
s = '''Name Sales Time
       Jame 603   14:59
       Sam  903   34:00
       Lee  756   34:55'''

df = (pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), 
                  sep='\s+', 
                  converters={'Time':lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%M:%S')})
      )


df['rate'] = df['Sales'] / (df['Time'].dt.minute + df['Time'].dt.second.div(60))
```